# Why does HashSet<Integer> store the integer value itself, but HashSet<Demo> stores the reference of the Demo object?

Tags: object, collections, set, wrapper, hashset

*Hi All,*

```
class Demo{
    private int a;
    Demo(int a){
        this.a = a;
    }
}

public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        
        Demo d1 = new Demo(10);
        Demo d2 = new Demo(20);
        
        Set<Demo> set = new HashSet<Demo>();
        
        set.add(d1);
        set.add(d2);
        
        System.out.println(set);
    }
}
```

**Output**: [javaSE_8.Demo@15db9742, javaSE_8.Demo@6d06d69c]

I understand that the above code is printing the object reference.

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        
        Integer i1 = 10;
        Integer i2 = 20;
        
        Set<Integer> set = new HashSet<Integer>();
        
        set.add(i1);
        set.add(i2);
        
        System.out.println(set);
    }
}
```

**Output**: [20, 10]

Where as this code prints the value itself in-spite of Integer being a class(Wrapper class) and i1, i2 being its objects.

I want to know why is this happening, or why does this difference exist.

*Thank you,
Suthan*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `HashSet<Demo>` and `HashSet<Integer>` store references to object.

`System.out.println(set)` prints the `String` returned by `set.toString()` method. This method calls `object.toString()` for each `object` in the set and concatenates them with a space.

Now because `Integer.toString()` returns the actual value as a `String`, you are seeing the value being printed for `Integer` whereas in the case of `Demo`, `Demo.toString()` returns the object reference as a `String` since it is the default  method  [`java.lang.Object.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString()). You can override this method in `Demo` to return the actual value as a `String`.

Comment: Yeah that is true. But when I change the value of Integer.i2, say i2 = 30 and try to do set.remove(i2) it doesn't remove any item from the set and the size of the set remains to be 2. Where as when I do the same with demo.d2 the item which was previously d2 is being removed and the size of the set becomes 1.

Comment: `Integer` is a [wrapper class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) for primitive `int` type. When you do i2 = 30, think of creating a new Integer object with value 30 and assigning it to i2. Now this i2 is different from the one inside the set.

Comment: @ShriramRamesh what do you mean with “when I do the same with demo.d2”? Doing the same would imply doing an assignment. Any assignment, except for a redundant `d2 = d2` would exhibit the same behavior as with `i2 = 30`; a `remove(d2)` would not remove the old object reference.

Comment: @Holger, sorry I meant doing the same with Demo.d2.a as d2.a = 30.

Comment: But then, it’s not the same. Assigning a reference variable is a fundamentally different thing than assigning a field of a referenced object.